# Rails: Given an Active_Relation is it possible to determine the query that generated it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have an Active_Relation object `issues`.

```
    issues = Issue.joins(:language).where(languages: { name: 'C' })
```

Without knowing what the originally query was, is there a way to determine the query from the object alone? Specifically, is it possible to determine which conditions were supplied to the `WHERE` clause?

Something like:

```
    > issues.where_conditions
    =>  { languages: { name: 'C' } }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do have a few public methods for this.  I normally inspect using `to_sql` b/c it tells me what will be executed, which is normally what i'm looking to know.

There is also [`where_values_hash`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6c6c32463e71af4e3395a691052a89c4c1571acd/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation.rb#L547) and [`joined_includes_values`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6c6c32463e71af4e3395a691052a89c4c1571acd/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation.rb#L566)